# How to Lock Range with more than 2 If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

Is it Lock cell with more than 2 "IF" statement.

Example : I want to Check each row ("L12:L48") if there is value between 1100000 ~ 1149999 then use`MsgBox` . If value more than 1150000 then use `MsgBox` and lock other cell ("E12:E28").

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer

i = 12

Do
    If Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1100000 And Cells(i, 12).Value <= 1149999 Then
        MsgBox "Caution : Cutter Meter Nearly Exceed Limit"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
        MsgBox "Please Change Cutter"
    ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Range("E12:E48").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 48

End Sub
```

I already run this code but `MsgBox` keep appear until reach last checked row (b'coz I use accumulate calculation on checked row) and cell lock is not function. Please open picture link below for excel view.

Can this be achieved using VBA and if so, how?

Many thanks.

[Locked Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKFx.png)

Comment: Why don't you just merge the 2 condition into 1 condition?

Answer (score 1):

Won't changing

From

```
If Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1100000 And Cells(i, 12).Value <= 1149999 Then
    MsgBox "Caution : Cutter Meter Nearly Exceed Limit"
ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
    MsgBox "Please Change Cutter"
ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("E12:E48").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
```

To

```
If Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1100000 And Cells(i, 12).Value <= 1149999 Then
    MsgBox "Caution : Cutter Meter Nearly Exceed Limit"
ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
    MsgBox "Please Change Cutter"
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If Range("E12:E48").MergeCells = False Then
        Range("E12:E48").Locked = True
    Else
        Range("E12:E48").MergeArea.Locked = True
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect
End If
```

Solve your problem?

Comment: Still got error at "Range("E12:E48")Locked.True 
Open this Url : http://imgur.com/8o2batq
Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveSheet.Range("E12:E48").Cells.Locked = True`?

Comment: What is the specific error? Chat me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129008/how-to-lock-range-with-more-than-2-if-statement

Comment: Eduard Daduya - yes column E n k are merged... I will check latter your attched link... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Static bWarning As Boolean

i = 12

```
Do
    If bWarning = False Then
        If Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1100000 And Cells(i, 12).Value <= 1149999 Then
            MsgBox "Caution : Cutter Meter Nearly Exceed Limit"
            bWarning = True
        ElseIf Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1150000 Then
            MsgBox "Please Change Cutter"
            bWarning = True
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            Range("E12:K48").Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect
        End If
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop Until i = 48
```

End Sub

*Ok guys... I already solve the problem.. Both of them... 1) Lock area in merged cell (2)Stop msgBox from multiple pop-up...
*Thank You Very much for your quick respond... Really appreciate...
:)